# No grub in bios boot after install

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, boot-repair, grub-efi

This is a fresh install on UEFI system. I set up 5 partitions on an nvme ssd:

1. 1GB /boot
2. 16MB biosgrub
3. 512MB efi partition
4. 50GB / root
5. 450GB unused partition (for steam)

/home is located in a separate physical drive, also new (no data in it)

After install, when I choose to boot from the nvme, I only see blank screen with blinking underscore. I tried boot-repair from a livecd but it says no internet connection. I tried to turn off internet related functions, and it asks me to add x86 efi repository. I don't know how to do that

I tried to use update-grub but it says no canonical path for /cow. I mounted the efi partition and tried grub-install --efi-directory but it says "can't find disk"

The partitions were created from scratch via ubuntu installer

Not sure what else can be done at this point

Comment: Why are you forcing Legacy in a UEFI system?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by forcing Legacy in a UEFI system. I'm under the impression that /boot is for ubuntu system booting, biosgrub is for the grub entry, and efi is for launching linux boot sequence in the first place @GabrielaGarcia